# How to get the created filename when a user uploads a file to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When a user uploads an image to Google Cloud Storage, I need to get the filename (hashed name in the Cloud, not user's filename) to be able to delete the file after.

I've read the issue:

`BlobService.getUploads()` returns `BlobStore.blobKeys` even when using GS.
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8337

In GAE SDK 1.7.5 release notes:

> The Blobstore service now returns the created filename instead of the blobKey when using Cloud Storage.

However, I don't know how to get the created filename by Blobstore service.

My code:

```
icon = self.get_uploads('icon')
if icon:
    blob_info = icon[0] 
    img_key = str(blob_info.key())
    img_filename = blob_info.filename
    img_size = blob_info.size
    img_type = blob_info.content_type
    img_creation = blob_info.creation
    img_url = images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key())
```

Thanks for your help.

**Update:**

Finally I google and get the issue:

`self.get_uploads('file')`[0] returns `BlobStore.blobKeys` even when using GS.
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9051

the magic codes:

```
fileInfo = blobstore.parse_file_info(self.request.POST['file'])
logging.info(fileInfo.gs_object_name)
```

It works!

So I can use the gs_object_name to delete file:

```
files.delete(fileInfo.gs_object_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "filename", you can just use the "blobKey" for most of the operation including deleting a file

Answer (score 0):

There is a `get_file_infos` method of `BlobstoreUploadHandler` now.

[How to get FileInfo/gcs file_name for files uploaded via BlobstoreUploadHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116672/how-to-get-fileinfo-gcs-file-name-for-files-uploaded-via-blobstoreuploadhandler/20682293#20682293)