# How to get FileInfo/gcs file_name for files uploaded via BlobstoreUploadHandler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

blobstore.parse_file_info(cgi.FieldStorage()['file']) method doesn't work for BlobstoreUploadHandler, the FieldStorage seems to be for regular uploads

There is no gcs filename information inside the blob_info that the regular blob_info from  self.get_uploads provides

It seems only a blob_key can be accessed using the regular methods, however a gcs file_name seems to be the safest bet for future

How can I get gcs file_name of a file uploaded to an url from blobstore.create_upload_url with gs_bucket_name argument?

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you are getting when using parse_file_info? I doubt it works for parse_blob_info and not for parse_file _info. Note that if you are using BlobstoreUploadHandler you can also use the method get_file_infos (analogous to get_uploads).

Comment: the cgi.FieldStorage() is always empty at BlobstoreUploadHandler - so the error is KeyError, can easily be produced on both sdk/appengine, get_file_infos is the solution to gs integration, a must know, thanks for letting me know, however it's not documented - no results: https://developers.google.com/search/results?q=get_file_infos&p=%2Fappengine it should be documented, there are many gcs examples, they all omit the BlobstoreUploadHandler integration

Comment: It is documented, however there are no examples. The problem is not that the function is not working, but how you are using it. cgi.FieldStorage(), will create and empty field, it won't pull the information from the request. You actually need to pull that data from the params. See the code for get_file_infos in BlobstoreUploadHandler. But as I said before, it's better to use directly the method BlobstoreUploadHandler.get_file_infos.

Answer (score 5):

```
class UploadAPI(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        file_info = self.get_file_infos()[0]

        rtn_data = {
            "filename": file_info.filename,
            "content_type": file_info.content_type,
            "creation": file_info.creation,
            "size": file_info.size,
            "md5_hash": file_info.md5_hash,
            "gs_object_name": file_info.gs_object_name
        }
```

I did find the usage in code, but I cannot find document either.

In 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclass said.

> If you're using the webapp or webapp2 application framework, you can
>   use the BlobstoreUploadHandler for more convenient parsing of this
>   information.

But there is nothing related to `FileInfo` I can find in document of `BlobstoreUploadHandler`
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers