# Uploading a file to GCS in GAE (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Im uploading files to my buckets in GCS thru GAE

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload', gs_bucket_name='my_bucket')
```

as described in the documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823206/upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-from-appengine-app)

Everything works fine, but, when I try to read the contents I find that the filename is being changed to a key value such as:

```
L2FwcGhvc3RpbmdfcHJvZC9ibG9icy9BRW5CMlVwOW93MmJzVWRyZ2RQSHJpMlNhMkZNUkloYm9xcnZnZlFzNEZCYnpWaGNENGkROOFk5b2pHSHBMcDIwcGVrVFZtYzdROHRDRWFpdy50YTNpMFdpNmNCQU9NU0xt
```

Is there any way to get the uploaded name of the file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage
"In your upload handler, you need to process the returned FileInfo metadata and explicitly store the GCS filename needed to retrieve the blob later."

More on FileInfo: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclass

and I think this question is similar to [How to get FileInfo/gcs file_name for files uploaded via BlobstoreUploadHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116672/how-to-get-fileinfo-gcs-file-name-for-files-uploaded-via-blobstoreuploadhandler)